# iOS WebRTC Handle Packet Loss

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, libjingle

I have a webRTC web app and an iOS WebRTC app. Both are using pubnub for signaling and this is working. I am using Xirsys for ICE. Everything works between the ios app and the web app until a packet is lost from web to ios. Once a packet is lost from the web video feed to the ios video feed the web video feed cuts out. But if a packet is lost from the ios app to the web app there is no problem.

On the iOS side I am using `libjingle_peerconnection` to handle the peer connections. Is there a way on the iOS side to just reduce the quality when packets are missing as opposed to just closing the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the libjingle_peerconnection cocoapod is so old that it is no longer compatible with Chrome 56+. See [here](https://medium.com/@fippo/when-a-browser-update-breaks-your-native-app-for-a-change-3845b30ea185) for more details including a workaround if you can't upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Philipp Hancke!! What is best to upgrade to? or could you elaborate on the workaround? How do I disabled RTX/RED? Thanks Again!

Comment: upgrading: currently the best option is to build webrtc on your own as described on https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

removing rtx/red: you have to remove the payload types for rtx and red from the SDP both in offers created as well as offers received. The picture in the article shows how to search for the payload types and the associated lines. [This article](https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/) might be useful as background